# CSS- :last-child that has "xyz" class name selector? Plain CSS/ LESS

Tags: html, css, dom

I know last-child is the last child of it's parent.

```
<div class"parent">
    <div class="child a"></div>
    <div class="child b"></div>
    <div class="child c"></div>
    <div class="child d"></div>
    <div class="child d"></div>
    <div class="child d"></div>
    <div class="child d"></div>
    <div class="child e"></div>
</div>
```

Here,

```
.child:last-child{
    /*This will grab .child.e  as it's the last child of it's parent*/
}
```

I want to select the last `.child.d` using `:last-child` selector. (the last `.child` that has `d` class )?
What is the CSS selector? (no Javascript please!)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:last-of-type` is not working for me
I'm writing postCSS. For some reason this isn't working

```
.roomOffered{
    &__single{
        border-bottom: 1px solid $color__skipper--fade3;
        padding: 3.5rem 0 3rem;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        &:last-of-type{
            border-bottom: none;
        }
    }
}
```

The last `.roomOffered__single` 's border-bottom isn't removed!!

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `:nth-child` selector but it won't let you target `.d` class...

So, this is the only viable solution i see:

```css
.child {
  padding: 10px;
  background: blue;
  border: solid 1px; 
}

.d {
  background: green;
}

.subparent .d:last-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class"parent">
    <div class="child a"></div>
    <div class="child b"></div>
    <div class="child c"></div>
    <div class="subparent">
      <div class="child d"></div>
      <div class="child d"></div>
      <div class="child d"></div>
      <div class="child d"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child e"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you wrote I explained on that my question. Actually I wanted the solution like `:last-of-type` !!

Comment: `:last-of-xxx` selector will only target the `div` not the class. So there is no way to do it like that...